# CSS adjacent selector nested

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, styles

Bootstrap button blocks use an adjacent selector to divide buttons.

```css
.btn-block + .btn-block {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

I have a dome tree where my bootstrap btn-blocks are going to be nested within shims. How do I use the same adjacency rule use by Bootstrap to create a margin for my elements?

```html
   <div class="col-md-4">
<span id=" "><input type="hidden" name=" " id=" ">
    <input type="submit" name=" " value=" " onclick=" " id=" " class="btn btn-primary btn-block"></span>
<span id=" "><input type="hidden" name=" " id=" ">
    <input type="submit" name=" " value=" " onclick=" " id=" " class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
</span>
<input type="submit" class=" btn-block btn btn-primary">
<input type="submit" id="ctl00_ctl00_cpContent_cpDetails_efvOrder_tslUsers_btnClear" class=" btn-block btn btn-primary">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you will have a bootstrap button inside of another element. So what you could do is give each container element a class like `btn-container`

Then you could use the child selector `.btn-container > .btn-block {` to give it the styling it needs.